# How to write this CSS-Selector (Target img from previous Anchor-Tag)

Tags: css, css-selectors

Basically I have this markup:

```
<a>Link</a>
<a>
  <img />
</a>
```

I would like to target the img on hover of the first Anchor-Tag. I have tried this

```
a:hover + a > img { ... }
```

but it didn't work. How could this be achieved?

Comment: Define "didn't work", because it certainly *should* and, indeed, [*does*](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/eEnTN/) (in Chrome, on Win XP).

Comment: Okay thanks, then it must be something else I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not in the selector `a:hover + a > img` is formed correctly.

### fiddle

Comment: Er so what's the problem or the solution then?

Comment: I found out what the problem was. Wordpress added some extra markup to my page, that's why the selector failed. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write like this.  This is an example I gave to give you clear idea about how to write the code.   **Even your code formation was correct.**

```
    <a>Link</a>
     <a>
    <div>fgfgfg</div>
     </a>


 a div:hover{
      background-color:blue;
     }
   div{
       width:100px;
       background-color:red;
    }
```

Here is the demo http://jsfiddle.net/ZWhtQ/